# Does anyone have any idea what this is?

Tags: bedroom

This reddish-brown thing came up over 4 months. Is this mould or something else entirely? We found this under our latex mattress protector and that has a little bit of it too. 
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This looks like mold, but we can't really tell from here, and this isn't really on-topic for this site.

Comment: This looks like mold to me is this edge of the bed against a wall, I have seen moisture cause problems on bedding where the mattress was close to a wall picking up moisture, a weak hydrogen peroxide and water (3% peroxide possibly less) would be my choice to eradicate the growth, and moving the bed a few inches away from the wall may be enough to prevent it from continuing to grow, a dehumidifier may also help.